# Is it possible to disable mdframed package of showing any content

Tags: mdframed

I use the `mdframed` package a lot while drafting my report, mainly by using colors to call my attention to the need to rework these parts.
Now I have to send a pdf without any of this content that needs reworking, but I wouldn't like to comment out each and every occurrence of `mdframed`.
Is it possible to (temporarily) inhibit the "printing" of any `mdframed` content?

```
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20]
I do not want this content to be printed.
\end{mdframed}
```

I have tried the following options without success:

```
\renewenvironment{mdframed}{}{}
```

and

```
\let\mdfsetup\relax\vspace{0pt}
\let\begin{mdframed}\relax\vspace{0pt}
\let\end{mdframed}\relax\vspace{0pt}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a current LaTeX you can grab the body and then throw it away:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{mdframed}{+b}{}{}
\begin{document}

Text before the environment

\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20]
I do not want this content to be printed.
\end{mdframed}

Text after the enviroment
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this for specific styles? E.g. let the content out if I use `[style=mystyle]` as option in the mdframed?

Comment: sure, check the optional argument and define suitable keys.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what to do. Could you be more explicit please?

Comment: no sorry I have no time now. Ask a new question (and this time add a complete minimal example). Or check the tcolorbox package, it has various options like "ignored" and "invisible" to hide content.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't know `\RenewDocumentEnvironment`, which is obviously better than my answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer fair enough. I made a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672801/disable-specific-styles-of-mdframed-package-of-showing-any-content

Answer (score 1):

You can uses this (I show what don't work, and with steps, how to achieve the goal).

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

Text before the environment

\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20]
I do not want this content to be printed.
\end{mdframed}

Text after the environment

\renewenvironment{mdframed}{}{} % Doesn't do what we expected (displays options and content)

First trial: 

\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20]
I do not want this content to be printed.
\end{mdframed}

Text after the first trial

\renewenvironment{mdframed}[1][]{}{} % capture the options (one optional argument, by default nothing. Doesn't  what we expected (displays still the content)

Second trial:

\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20]
I do not want this content to be printed.
\end{mdframed}

Text after the second trial

\newsavebox{\mybox} % creates a box to saving the content to display. As we don't uses the saved box, the text from the environment isn't displayed
\renewenvironment{mdframed}[1][]{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}}{\end{lrbox}} % works yet 

Third trial:

\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20]
I do not want this content to be printed.
\end{mdframed}

Text after the third trial

\end{document}
```

You obtain this:

[image]

Comment: The answer from Ulrike Fischer is obviously better, using the recent LaTeX command `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` which I did not know (It comes from `xparse` package and LaTeX3, recently integrated in LaTeX2e).

Comment: Thank you anyways.