# Disable specific styles of mdframed package of showing any content

Tags: mdframed

In this recent [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672707/is-it-possible-to-disable-mdframed-package-of-showing-any-content/672756?noredirect=1#comment1671757_672756) I found how I could disable all instances of `mdframed` of showing any content.
This is done elegantly through `\RenewDocumentEnvironment{mdframed}{+b}{}{}`.

Now, I'd like to know how may I apply this only to specific `mdframed` styles.
Here is a working minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{show}{leftmargin=1cm,linecolor=gray, roundcorner=10pt, align=center, userdefinedwidth=.9\linewidth, nobreak=true}
\mdfdefinestyle{draftA}{hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20}
\mdfdefinestyle{draftB}{hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=green!20}

%\RenewDocumentEnvironment{mdframed}{+b}{}{} % With this line uncommented, all mdframed are not sent to the output

\begin{document}

Text before the environment

\begin{mdframed}[style=draftA]
I do not want this content to be printed.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[style=draftB]
I do not want this content to be printed.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[style=show]
I do want this content to be printed.
\end{mdframed}

Text after the environment
\end{document}
```

This outputs the following:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a [great help from David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673069/132405) for a specific problem, I'm able to provide a solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{show}{leftmargin=1cm,linecolor=gray, roundcorner=10pt, align=center, userdefinedwidth=.9\linewidth, nobreak=true}
\mdfdefinestyle{draftA}{hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!20}
\mdfdefinestyle{draftB}{hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=green!20}

\NewCommandCopy\oldmdframed\mdframed
\NewCommandCopy\endoldmdframed\endmdframed

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{mdframed}{o +b}{% begin part
    \ifstrequal{#1}{style=show}{% true part
        \oldmdframed[style=show]#2\endoldmdframed}{% false part
    }}{% end part
}


\begin{document}

Text before the environment

\begin{mdframed}[style=draftA]
I do not want this content to be printed.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[style=draftB]
I do not want this content to be printed.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[style=show]
I do want this content to be printed.
\end{mdframed}

Text after the environment
\end{document}
```

You obtain:

[image]

Note that the command `\ifstrequal` comes from the `etoolbox` package, which is automatically loaded by `mdframed`.

Comment: Perhaps there are equivalents in the kernel/l3, but I don't think the literal command `\ifstrequal` is provided by base LaTeX. mdframed does load etoolbox, so in that sense the line `\usepackage{etoolbox}` can be commented

Comment: @mbert I have edited the answer with your clarification, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect.